# How to prevent markers overlaping other markers on map using QGIS 2.2.0

Tags: qgis, point, style

I have points with similar coordinates and displaying them on a map of Latvia they overlapping. How can I display all the points using QGIS 2.2.0 like in Finnish map?[image: Latvia] [image: Finland]

Comment: If some of your points have the exact same coordinates, you can use the **Points Displacement** style (_Layer Properties > Style > click "Single Symbol"_) and edit the settings to offset the overlapping points.

Comment: Thaks for the ansver, but I dont have points with same coordinates.

Comment: I don't think there's a one-click solution to this (unless I missed something). You could create a _Categorised_, _Graduated_ or _Rule-based_ style and change the **offset** settings for points of a certain value.

Comment: Is there any way to do it manually by hand?

Comment: Dont know if it was already available in QGIS 2.2 but on later version i think you can use a data defined offset. So the offset for each point is stored in the dataset. Depending on where your data is stored you could also define complex offset rules directly inside a PostGis database using SQL if needed.

Comment: Actually I checked with 2.6 and you can for sure use a data defined offset. So the offset for each point is stored in your dataset so you can manually edit it for each point. Maybe some plugin will even help you do that (I know it exist for label, not sure for features)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would approach this through two steps:

- Install the MMQGIS plugin, available via `Manage and install plugins...`, then use the `Gridify` option to set the points out uniformly to a grid.
- Set the categorised style of your points to something that would look legible when overlapping. Make sure the larger of the two shapes has no 'fill', so it won't hide the smaller shape.

Here's a rough example. Obviously you'll want to experiment with grid scale and symbols size to best visualise your data.

[image]

As some of your points will now share coordinates you would be able to use **point displacement**, as Joseph suggested, as an alternative if that would suit your needs better.